# what does -at- suffix do

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, grammar, affixes

in dictionary of lenru, the "amato" word(which means beloved), is built by am + at + o. I searched in suffixes of esperanto, but I didn't find anything about -at- suffix. so what does it do?

Comment: And a parallel: _-ant-_ as in _amanto_ for _lover_,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suffix *-at* denotes the passive present tense participle: someone or something who/which is currently influenced by the action of the root. Here you have the noun (*-o*), which are taken to mean humans if otherwise not indicated, so the *amato* is the person who is loved or in short beloved.

Take a look at the grammar section of the [participles](https://lernu.net/gramatiko/participoj) at the site Lernu. (Note, you can change the language of the page at the bottom right.)

Answer (score 1):

The -at- suffix is the present passive participle. When used with -o, it signifies a person that is having an action done to them. So in this case an *amato* is someone that is being loved. A *serĉato* would be someone that is being searched for.

Note that the *a* in *-ato* is the same as the *a* in the present tense suffix *-as*. This isn’t a coincidence. In fact, you can use the other two tenses in a similar way. For example *trovito* woud be someone that has been found (like the *-is* verb ending). *Manĝoto* is someone that will be eaten etc.

You can find more about this in the [grammar section of Lernu](https://lernu.net/gramatiko/participoj#participoj-substantivoj).